# Read CPU temp in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can i read cpu temperature in react native ?  The npm package react-native-device-info https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info#api  does not have a temp property.

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can use nodejs for this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation

Comment: It is `node.js` library and the question was regarding `react native`